# Delete rows where checkbox is true and delete sheet where name matches value in checked row

Tags: arrays, for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to write a script that checks rows and deletes rows where a checkbox is checked. The part where I'm stuck is that I have a script that also creates a new sheet and names it the the value of a cell in these rows. I'd like to be able to delete the sheet that matches the value in the row that gets deleted.

The example code for the function that deletes the row.

```
function deleteOldData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("INCOMING");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  const receivedCol = ws.getRange("H:H").getValues()

  var buttonPressed = ui.alert("WARNING: The following action is unrecoverable would you still like to execute?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if(buttonPressed == ui.Button.YES){
    for(let i = receivedCol.length-1;i >= 0;i--){
    if(receivedCol[i][0] === true) {
      ***I want to check the values in a cell of rows checked true, store the values and delete the sheets where name is equal to the values***
      ws.deleteRow(i+1)
    }
    } 
  }
}
```

I was able to delete sheets named after a specific cell but not able to delete every sheet for every row that's checked.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and `I want to check the values in a cell of rows checked true, store the values and delete the sheets where name is equal to the values`. And also, I cannot understand the relationship between the checkbox and `store the values and delete the sheets where name is equal to the values` and your script. Can I ask you the detail of your question?

Comment: The script that I provided as an example checks my sheet named INCOMING for cells in column H for checkboxes marked true. If there are cells checked true, the script deletes the row from the sheet via a button. What I'd like to be able to do is: when the script finds a row that is marked true in column H, I want it to take the value in column C of the same row and delete the sheet that has a name of the same value in column C of the INCOMING sheet. This script will delete all rows checked true, I'd like it to delete all sheets that have a matching name to the values of the rows being deleted.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: My script deletes rows from the sheet where column H:H = true. In column C:C there is a string value. Additionally, there is a separate sheet that is named after the string value in column C:C of the "Incoming" sheet. When my script deletes rows where H:H = true, I want it to also delete the separate sheet where sheetName == 'Incoming'!C:C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question with some fiddling with the function.

The code below executes as intended:

```
function deleteOldData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("INCOMING");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  const receivedCol = ws.getRange("H:H").getValues()

  var buttonPressed = ui.alert("WARNING: The following action is unrecoverable would you still like to execute?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if(buttonPressed == ui.Button.YES){
    for(let i = receivedCol.length-1;i >= 0;i--){
    if(receivedCol[i][0] === true) {
      let orderNum = ws.getSheetValues(i+1,3,1,1)
      let orderSheet = ss.getSheetByName(orderNum);
      ss.deleteSheet(orderSheet);
      ws.deleteRow(i+1)
    }
    } 
  }
}
```